# Spacing issues about multiple-layer bcc structure

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, crystallography, physical-properties-of-materials, computational-frameworks

I am trying to make Hartree potential of bcc Tungsten(001).
My software is VASP.
5-layer should have 5 bound states.
But I don't have them
I heard it is a layer-layer spacing issue.
I built slab of bcc structre :

POSCAR

```
a1 = a(1 0 0)
a2 = a(0 1 0)
a3 = a(0 0 50)
```

and with direct,

```
0    0    0.02
0.5  0.5  0.01
0    0    0
0.5  0.5 -0.01
0    0   -0.02
```

[image: My result]

the z space should be 1/(2*50) = 0.01?

It seems z-direction spacing has a problem.

Comment: +1 and welcome to the site! We hope to see more of you!
 I see that you recently joined Math.SE, and I wonder how you found MM.SE?

Answer (score 3):

You might be overlapping the W atoms on the unit cell.
Try taking a bulk unit cell of W, creating a slab along the (001) direction with the desired thickness using the [VESTA software](https://jp-minerals.org/vesta/en/) according to the instructions in [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6xx29-CQJiA&ab_channel=NickelandCopper).
VESTA is capable of exporting for you the POSCAR, which you can then use in VASP, and you will get the correct Coulomb potential.